# How to get second combobox value after first one changed (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, combobox, onchange

I have 2 comboboxes, first for Province and second for city/town.

I just wanna get the value of my second combobox (city/town) after first combobox changed and second combobox will change with ajax after user chose first the combobox.

Here is my code, but the problem is that the alert shows up twice!

```
jQuery('#billing_state').on('change', function() {
    jQuery('#billing_city').on('change', function() {
          var state = jQuery(this).val();
          alert(state);
    });

});
```

Comment: This can be done by using ajax.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Hey Masoud does it make sens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you made an imbrication of event ? just use change on the first combo .

Here is an example :

```js
state = {"1":["Rome","Milan","Parma"],"2":["Paris","Lile","Nice"],"3":["Algiers","Jijel","Bejaia"],"4":["London","Manchester"]}


$(document).ready(function(){
 //this if you want that changing province this alert country value
    $("#billing_state").on("change",function(e){
       
          $("#billing_town").children().remove();
          var city =state[$(this).val()];
          if(!city) return;
          $("#billing_town").append('<option value="">- Select -</option>')
          for(i=0; i< city.length;i++) {
            //console.log(city[i]);
            $("#billing_town").append('<option value="'+city[i]+'">'+city[i]+'</option>');
          }
          
    });
  
    // when changing country this alert country value itself
    $("#billing_town").on("change",function(e){
       alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Province :
<select id="billing_state">
  <option value="">- select -</option>
  <option value="1">Italy</option>
  <option value="2">France</option>
  <option value="3">Algeria</option>
  <option value="4">UK</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Country : 
<select id="billing_town">
</select>
```

Comment: this code alerted value after u change first combobox twice

Comment: No , it alert just once

Comment: No i mean when you change first combobox it alert value of second one..but i want when u change first combo nothing happen just second combo value change then when u change second combobox(town) it alert the value

Comment: when you change the first combo what happen to the second ? you affect a new value to it ?

Comment: In this Case yes you are right..but in my case when you change first combobox second combo value change with ajax and then it wont work and second on wont alert

Comment: yes exactly for example in first one u choose italy and then in second one appear roma , milan and ...

Comment: Nice copy&paste template for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want. try with demo below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">


</style>

<body>
 
<label>Province</label>
<select id="province">
 <option>california</option>
 <option>austin</option>
 <option>texas</option>
 <option>colombo</option>
</select>

<hr>

<label>city</label>
<select id="city">
 <option>colombo</option>
 <option>canberra</option>
 <option>silicon valley</option>
 <option>ottawa</option>
</select>
 

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 $("#province").on('change',function(){// in this line identify if there is any changes to first select box
  var thevalue = $("#city").val(); // if there is any changes to first selection box, then at that time get the value of second selection box.
  alert(thevalue); // to check the value of secod check box at the time chage put an alert.
 });

</script>
</html>
```

**or else if your want to show values according to user selection of first select box value, you can do it like this.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">


</style>

<body>
 
<label>Province</label>
<select id="province">
 <option>california</option>
 <option>austin</option>
 <option>ottawa</option>
 <option>western</option>
</select>

<hr>

<label>City</label>
<select id="city">
 <option>--select--</option>
</select>
 

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 

$("#province").on('change',function(){// in this line identify if there is any changes to first select box
  var thevalue = $(this).val(); // if there is any changes to first selection box, then at that time get the 
  $("#city").text("");
    //display values according to the first value
    if (thevalue == "california") 
    {
         var cities = ["sillicon valley","st pauls","new york"];
         for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++)
         {
          var createoption = $('<option>'+cities[i]+'</option>');
          $("#city").append(createoption);
         }
    }
    else if(thevalue="austin")
    {
     var cities = ["mirage","manhatten","las vegas"];
         for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++)
         {
          var createoption = $('<option>'+cities[i]+'</option>');
          $("#city").append(createoption);
         }
    }
    else
    {
     //like above you can add relevent values.
    }


 });


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: No..i want when you change country the value of country alert..this alert country value when u change province value

Comment: try now , i changed it

Comment: thanks alot i tried but not working yet...attention that when u are choosing first combo it alert but i dont want that.. i want when you change second combo it alert value of itself

Comment: when you `change` the first `box` it shows the value of `second` box. see it carefully and change the data as your need. these are `dummy data`.
and also I have added another method that if user change `first box`, that will change the `second box` values according to first change.try it also.

Comment: Try to use my first code ..i exactly want that result but without two alert

Comment: yes second one change of u change first one thats ok but i want to alert the second one immidiatly after it choosed